# How to remove code smell: getSessionFactory, create SessionFactory only when necessary

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, design-patterns, factory

I use hibernate to handle the connection to the DB. I have several Session Factories that connect to different schemas.

Building all SessionFactory on startup takes at least 60 seconds. So I only have them be built when necessary:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory factory_db1;
    private static SessionFactory factory_db2;
    //...

    public enum DbSchema {
      db1, db2 //...
    }        

    private createSessionFactory(Configuration conf){
    //...
    }

    public static SessionFactory getFactory(DbSchema dbSchema) {

      try {
        switch (dbSchema) {
            case db1:
                if (factory_db1== null){
                    Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure(HIBERNATE_CFG_DB1);
                    factory_db1= createSessionFactory(conf);
                }
                return factory_db1;
            case db2:
                if (factory_db2 == null){
                    Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure(HIBERNATE_CFGXML_DB2);
                    factory_ooarchive = createSessionFactory(conf);
                }
                return factory_ooarchive;
            //... more factories created
            default:
                assert false : "Switch default should not be reachable.";
                return null;
        }
      } catch (Throwable ex) {
        log.error("Failed to initialize SessionFactory." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Now when I access this factory:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getFactory(db1).openSession();
// **Compiler warning: method invocation may produce java.lang.nullpointerexception**
```

Getting the factory is only possible through the getFactory() method therefore I would think a NPE is never possible. I understand that the problem is the static keyword for the factory instance variable and that there is no initilization in the contructor. I do not want this "always-on" initilization! It should only be initialized when needed at least once.

I read a few design pattern and code quality books but I struggle to implement what I learned. I think I created a code smell. How do I fix this design? Please explain my mistakes and why my choices are questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that the compiler warning (probably issued by an IDE and not `javac`) be related to the `static` modifier of `getFactory()`.

Actually `getFactory()` implementation declares a `switch` statement that has a `default` case that returns `null` :

```
default:
    assert false : "Switch default should not be reachable.";
    return null;
```

So `getFactory()` may indeed return `null` if the passed parameter doesn't allow to enter in one of the previous cases.

But I think that  the main issue of `getFactory()` is its lack of thread safety. Indeed, if multiple threads access it concurrently, you could create multiple sessions and maybe generate an inconsistent state.
As alternative, to create the sessions on demand, you could use a specific flavor of the singleton pattern : [the initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) :

> In software engineering, the initialization-on-demand holder (design
>   pattern) idiom is a lazy-loaded singleton. In all versions of Java,
>   the idiom enables a safe, highly concurrent lazy initialization with
>   good performance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not consider thread-safety. As a quick and dirty solution I added synchronize to all methods in HibernateUtil class. For the full solution I will implement the idiom you mentioned. Seems to be the best choice for lazy initilization.

Comment: You should indeed because if the method is very frequently invoked, it could generate some latency by making all methods synchronized.

Comment: I agree, that's why after a little bit of thinking I implemented it already!